# Python Pandas: Find the maximum for each row in a dataframe column containing a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got a Pandas DataFrame looking like the following:

```
      values                                      max_val_idx
0    np.array([-0.649626, -0.662434, -0.611351])            2
1    np.array([-0.994942, -0.990448, -1.01574])             1
2    np.array([-1.012, -1.01034, -1.02732])                 0
```

`df['values']` contains numpy arrays of a fixed length of 3 elements
`df['max_val_idx]` contains the index of the maximum value of the corresponding array

Since the index of the maximum element for each array is already given, what is the most efficient way to extract the maximum for each entry?
I know the data is stored somewhat silly, but I didn't create it myself. And since I got a bunch of data to process (+- 50GB, as several hundreds of pickled databases stored in a similar way), I'd like to know what is the most time efficient method.

So far I tried to loop over each element of `df['max_val_idx]` and use it as an index for each array found in `df['values']`:

```
max_val = []         
for idx, values in enumerate(df['values']):
     max_val.append(values[int(df['max_val_idx'].iloc[idx])])
```

Is there any faster alternative to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just forget the 'max_val_idx' column.  I don't think it saves time and actually is more of a pain for syntax.  Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x': range(3) }).applymap( lambda x: np.random.randn(3) )

                                                   x
0  [-1.17106202376, -1.61211460669, 0.0198122724315]
1    [0.806819945736, 1.49139051675, -0.21434675401]
2  [-0.427272615966, 0.0939459129359, 0.496474566...
```

You could extract the max like this:

```
df.applymap( lambda x: x.max() )

          x  
0  0.019812
1  1.491391
2  0.496475
```

But generally speaking, life is easier if you have one number per cell.  If each cell has an array of length 3, you could rearrange like this:

```
for i, v in enumerate(list('abc')): df[v] = df.x.map( lambda x: x[i] )
df = df[list('abc')]

          a         b         c
0 -1.171062 -1.612115  0.019812
1  0.806820  1.491391 -0.214347
2 -0.427273  0.093946  0.496475
```

And then do a standard pandas operation:

```
df.apply( max, axis=1 )

          x  
0  0.019812
1  1.491391
2  0.496475
```

Admittedly, this is not much easier than above, but overall the data will be much easier to work with in this form.

Comment: It might be advantageous to use `np.max(df, axis=1)` instead of applying Python's builtin `max` across the values since the numpy version can probably take more advantage of the DataFrame's underlying structure.

Comment: That's a good suggestion although I just tried and it was slower -- I'm not sure why.

Comment: @JohnE:  Thank you for the answer. After some quick testing of both solutions it seems like your first method is roughly 20 times faster and scales better when the value-arrays are becomming bigger. Since at this moment I don't need to do anything more with the data than extracting only one number from the 'value'-column, but I''ll keep your second method in mind if there is more work to be done on the data or if I have to select the value given by the idx-column in stead of just selecting the maximum.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting and surprising to me also (that the first way is faster).  Anyway, glad to see this and @scott's answer were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the speed of this will compare, since I'm constructing a 2D matrix of all the rows, but here's a possible solution:

```
>>> np.choose(df['max_val_idx'], np.array(df['values'].tolist()).T)
0   -0.611351
1   -0.990448
2   -1.012000
```

Comment: Since I asked for the maximum, I will have to accept the answer provided by @JohnE. However, in general, I''ll have to select the value according to the index given in de `df['max_val_idx']`-column too. In that particular case your solution comes in very handy. Unfortunately the `dtype` of the numbers in `df['max_val_idx']` is `float64`, and thus I'll have to find a work around to use these numbers as an index (it has something to do with safe int casting as far as I've read). Cheers!